# Должен ли проверяющий метод check/validate возвращать boolean или выбрасывать исключение?

Tags: php, рефакторинг, чистый-код

Этот вопрос не обязательно относится к *PHP*, просто это моя сфера.

При построении методов, которые "узнают" имеет ли объект/переменная что-то, разрешено ли что-то (is, has, can), то возвращается `true`/`false`. Тут всё понятно.

А если метод должен что-то проверить или свалидировать (`check()`/`validate()`), то что должно быть? Должен ли метод вернуть булево значение, на основе которого мы поймём, что что-то было некорректно? Или надо выбрасывать исключение (`throw new InvalidDataExecption`) и метод валидации оборачивать в `try/catch`? Какой правильный подход?

Во фреймворках при `vlaidate` возвращаются какие-то данные (true, false и даже массивы с ошибками), но ведь мы просто валидируем, а не говорим "Валидно ли вот это (isValid($data))", как в случае булевых запросов выше.

Answer (score 2):

Да как бы up to you. Может вам надо просто подсветить пропущенное при заполнении формы поле (тру/фолс). А может необходимо вывести дополнительное сообщение об ошибке (вот вам уже эррей). А где-то надо писать в лог ексепшены. Всё упирается в задачи, которые валидатор должен решать. имхо)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от логики метода. 
Например у вас есть метод **validateString**, который принимает аргументом строку. 
И что-то в ней проверяет. Тогда логично сделать результат true или false в зависимости от результата проверки, а exception уже бросать в случае если на проверку пришел не тот тип данных.

Другой пример. Если работа метода не возможна дальше, когда результат **false**, то тогда метод **validateString** возвращает true если проверка прошла, и бросаете exception если нет.

Comment: Если метод возвращает `true/false` его надо называть `isValidString`.

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны конечно было бы круто получить сразу ответ на просьбу валидации данных, но сам по себе метод `validate` (по смыслу) должен просто что-то сделать. Как раз, как указал, `check` и `validate` похожи на `void`.

С другой стороны, почему они что-то должны возвращать, если они походи на `void`. Поскольку, как сказано выше, все зависит от логики, то лично я бы предложил сформировать следующую логику:

1. Формируется класс валидации, где есть метод `validate`, который выкидывает какие-то исключения (их надо будет отлавливать)
2. В качестве обертки для случая `true/false`, я бы сделал метод `isValid`, который включал бы в себя `try` метода `validate` и делал `return` в случае успеха или неудачи

Как вариант еще один метод, который валидировал бы все данные без выбрасывания исключений. Он бы копил ошибки, а затем возвращал их (или пустой массив, если все корректно).

Таким образом, на одну только валидацию 3 реализации. Можно обернуть в абстрактный класс для дальнейшего использования. Ну тут уже персонально.